# Testing controller action for expected rendered view in Playframework 2.1

Tags: java, unit-testing, playframework-2.1

In playframework 2.1, is it possible to test an action to make sure the rendered view is the one I'm expecting for?

In ASP.NET MVC 3, `AssertViewRendered().ForView("view")` tests exactly that. Can we do it in play 2.1? How?

Very basic MVC 3 example of what I would like to achieve:

```
// Given the action GetUsers that renders the view "Users", I would like to assert
// this view as the one I expect and no other.
public class UserController
{
    public ActionResult Index() {
        return View("Users");
    }
}

[Test]
public void GetUsersRendersCorrectView()
{
    // Setup
    var userService = new Mock<UserService>();
    var userController = new UserController(userService.Object);

    // Excercise
    var result = userController.GetUsers();

    // Verify
    result.AssertViewRendered().ForView("Users");
}
```

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The view rendering in Play is only a method call (the templates are compiled to simple Scala functions).

Nothing prevents you to implement the view rendering with a "manually-built" function.

Therefore, the `Result` returned by the Action don't know if the content comes from a template or anything else. That's why the kind of assertion you want to achieve is not possible with Play.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure to fully understand, but I think you can test your controller, and the rendered view by asserting that the rendered view contains some expected data.

From the [Playframework documentation](http://www.playframework.com/documentation/2.1.1/JavaFunctionalTest):

```
@Test
public void callIndex() {
    Result result = callAction(
      controllers.routes.ref.Application.index("Kiki")
    );
    assertThat(status(result)).isEqualTo(OK);
    assertThat(contentType(result)).isEqualTo("text/html");
    assertThat(charset(result)).isEqualTo("utf-8");
    assertThat(contentAsString(result)).contains("Hello Kitty");
}
```

Comment: Thanks nico_ekito for you answer, I'm aware about testing the content of a view, but thats not what I need in this case. I edited my post improving the example, hopefully it clarifies a bit :)

Comment: Since the invoked view is a method, it will hard to tell which method is called. Maybe by using a mocking framework to verify some behavior (http://mockito.googlecode.com/svn/branches/1.8.0/javadoc/org/mockito/Mockito.html#1).